# Multiple book click events

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a Minecraft map and for the games, I have a written book with a click event, but how do you put multiple click events in one book?

Comment: Could you paste the command you have so far into your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For books what you need to do is add on things called clickEvents after each command. So if you had a command that looked like this:

```
/tellraw @p ["",{"text":"Tp","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tp @p 100 100 100"}}
```

This gives you a `tp` command simply called Tp ("text":"Tp") that teleports you to 100 100 100.

What you would do to add a command is add a comma and start the next line of command:

```
,{"text":"Tp","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tp @p 120 100 100"}}]
```

This will teleport them 20 blocks higher then the last command.  If we add both commands together the end result should look like this:

```
  /tellraw @p ["",{"text":"Tp","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tp @p 100 100 100"}},{"text":"Tp","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/tp @p 100 100 100"}}]
```

There are book generators out there that will do this for you without the need to type it out yourself, This is a link to one that is fairly popular and works great:  https://www.minecraftjson.com/